# Capture table row when dropdown item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a table view and in the tableview each row I have dropdown menu.

I wonder there is a way to capture which dropdown item (tablerow 1 or tablerow 2, etc..) is being changed/selected.

**.TS**

```
constructor() {
   this.cars.push({label:'Honda', value:0},
                  {label:'Toyota', value:1},
                  {label:'Mazda', value:2},
                  {label:'Not Selected', value:3})
}

onSelectedItem(selectedCar) {
// could able to capture the value of the selected item from the dropdown, 
// but do not know which tablecell is...
    console.log(selectedCar);
}
```

**.HTML**

```
<table *ngIf="tableRows.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cars</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let car of tableRows">
                <p-dropdown [options]="cars"  [optionLabel]="label" placeholder="Select Car" 
                (onChange)="onSelectedItem($event.value)"></p-dropdown>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If yes, please add the details for the same.

Comment: I have added the code as well.

Comment: `ngFor="let car of tableRows"` is it rigth? shouldn't be `cars` instead `tableRows`

Answer (score 0):

if you just want index of the row then you can do it the following way:

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let car of tableRows; let i=index">
                <p-dropdown [options]="cars"  [optionLabel]="label" placeholder="Select Car" 
                (onChange)="onSelectedItem($event.value, i)">
</p-dropdown>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

or you can actually pass the object selected instead of just passing the value on select action of dropdown.

Comment: Getting index is undefined.

Comment: @hotspring: where in your code, have you defined tableRows? This array should be defined in your component as you are trying to iterate over it in the HTML.